# Having custom controls still apply when go fullscreen on a HTML5 video?

Tags: html, custom-controls, html5-video, fullscreen

I've made custom controls for my HTML5 video but I don't know how to have that CSS still apply when I go fullscreen.

Here's the [[website]](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/html5-video/demo1/) I've based my controls on.

On this site, you'll notice that when you click the fullscreen button the custom controls get lost and the video reverts to the default `<video>` controls.

Does anyone know how to have these custom controls styling/CSS still apply when you go fullscreen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i answered my own question, the key is that the custom controls are inside the `<div>` that includes the video that you want to take full screen. In my code below, this `<div>` is called  "videoContainer".

Here's the link I used to figure this out.
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html

here's the JS code for both entering and exiting fullscreen mode in webkit and mozilla browsers:

```
var $video=$('video');
//fullscreen button clicked
$('#fullscreenBtn').on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('enterFullscreenBtn');
    if($.isFunction($video.get(0).webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
              if($(this).hasClass("enterFullscreenBtn"))
                  document.getElementById('videoContainer').webkitRequestFullScreen();                          
              else 
              document.webkitCancelFullScreen();    
    }  
    else if ($.isFunction($video.get(0).mozRequestFullScreen)) {
              if($(this).hasClass("enterFullscreenBtn"))
                  document.getElementById('videoContainer').mozRequestFullScreen(); 
               else 
                  document.mozCancelFullScreen();   
    }
    else { 
           alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
    }
});
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
      <video>...<source></source>
      </video>
      <div> custom controls 
            <button>play/pause</button>
            <button id="fullscreenBtn" class="enterFullscreenBtn">fullscreen</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I think I finally got the hang of this. It's the container you take fullscreen, and the if the video and the custom controls are in that container, then you're good. The browsers will stop messing with you too, because you're not taking a video into fullscreen and they don't need to jump in and save the day with their wonky controls.

Comment: @CostaMichailidis you made my f**ing day! )) calling fullscreen on parent container works like charm, then I have same custom controls as in a small mode, react keep working fine in fullscreen also then. Googled for a solution almost 2 hours.

Comment: @NickShulzhenko Woohoo! I love when and old hack lives on : )

Comment: Can it auto rotate?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses the modern [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), which is supported on all major browsers today.

```js
// `container` is the element containing the video and your custom controls

const toggleFullscreen = () => {
    if(document.fullscreenElement) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else {
        container.requestFullscreen();
    }
};
```

Comment: yooo this is life saving,thx!

Answer (score 2):

**Show custom controller**

```
#customController{
  -------------------;
  -------------------;
  -------------------;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

**Hide native controller**

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display:none !important;
}
```