# HTML5 Video Fullscreen

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html5-video, fullscreen

I have try to make a HTML5 video player. I have created custom controls with CSS and jQuery. But when I am turn on full-screen mode, I can't see my custom controls on full-screen.

**Full-screen mode off:**

[image]

**Full-screen mode on but no custom controls:**

[image]

Comment: Does this help? [Having custom controls still apply when go fullscreen on a HTML5 video?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10115345/1456376) (Possible duplicate)

Comment: it's work but not perfectly. I am trying it to make this to perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Show custom controller**

Please add `z-index` in to your custom control element

```
#customController{
  -------------------;
  -------------------;
  -------------------;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

**Hide native controller**

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go fullscreen, it's the video element which getting fullscreen not the container which contains both control and video.

For example

```
<div class='container'>
    <vido></video>
    <div class='custom-controls'>...</div>
</div>
```

In JS 
do

> document.queryselector('.container').video.webkitExitFullscreen()

Instead

> document.queryselector('video').video.webkitExitFullscreen()

This is should work, I have tried it.